# How to get non ragged right column with NPOI

Tags: c#, excel, csv, xls, npoi

I have an `excel` (`.xls`) file that needs to be parsed into a `.csv` file. I am using the latest stable version of `NPOI` library for `c#`. The problem is I am getting ragged right `CSV` instead of getting normalized row size.

[What the data in excel file looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4qS3P.png)

The output `csv` file is:

> "FirstName","MiddleName","LastName","PhNum"
>
> "John","L","Doe","555-555-5555"
>
> "Little","Ding","Bat"
>
> "Roger","D","Rabbit","123-456-7890"

What I would like for it to happen is add an extra delimeter at the end of the second data row(after "Bat"), like so:

> "FirstName","MiddleName","LastName","PhNum"
>
> "John","L","Doe","555-555-5555"
>
> "Little","Ding","Bat",
>
> "Roger","D","Rabbit","123-456-7890"

Here is my code:

```
    public override bool ParseFile()
    {
        FileStream iFile = new FileStream(InputFileName, FileMode.Open);
        HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(iFile);
        ExcelExtractor extractor = new ExcelExtractor(wb);
        extractor.IncludeBlankCells = true;
        bool result = true;

        if (AllWorksheets)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < wb.NumberOfSheets; i++)
                result = result && ParseWorksheet(wb, i);
        }
        else
        {
            result = ParseWorksheet(wb, 0);
        }
        return result;
    }
    protected char c = '"';
    public static string FormatValue(string s, bool AddQuotes, char quoteChar)
    {
        if (AddQuotes)
        {
            return quoteChar + s + quoteChar;
        }
        return s;
    }
    private bool ParseWorksheet(HSSFWorkbook wb, int SheetIndex)
    {

        bool result = true;
        HSSFSheet sheet = (HSSFSheet)wb.GetSheetAt(SheetIndex);


        if (sheet.FirstRowNum == sheet.LastRowNum && sheet.LastRowNum == 0) return result;

        System.IO.StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(OutputFileName, true);

        for (int i = sheet.FirstRowNum; i <= sheet.LastRowNum; i++)
        {
            string OutputRow = String.Empty;
            HSSFRow row = (HSSFRow)sheet.GetRow(i);
            int Column = 0;
            int MaxCol = 0;
            int temp = 0;

            for (int j = 0; j < row.LastCellNum; j++)
            {
                temp = row.LastCellNum;
                if (temp > MaxCol)
                {
                    MaxCol = temp;
                }
            }
            for (int j = 0; j < MaxCol; j++)
            {
                if (j == row.Cells[Column].ColumnIndex)
                {
                    switch (row.Cells[Column].CellType)
                    {
                        case NPOI.SS.UserModel.CellType.Boolean:
                            OutputRow += FormatValue(row.Cells[Column].BooleanCellValue.ToString(), AddQuotes, c) + Delimiter.ToString();
                            break;
                        case NPOI.SS.UserModel.CellType.Formula:
                            OutputRow += FormatValue(row.Cells[Column].CachedFormulaResultType.ToString(), AddQuotes, c) + Delimiter.ToString();
                            break;
                        case NPOI.SS.UserModel.CellType.Numeric:
                            OutputRow += FormatValue((NPOI.SS.UserModel.DateUtil.IsCellDateFormatted(row.Cells[Column]) ? row.Cells[Column].DateCellValue.ToShortDateString() : row.Cells[Column].NumericCellValue.ToString()), AddQuotes, c) + Delimiter.ToString();
                            break;
                        case NPOI.SS.UserModel.CellType.Blank:
                            OutputRow += Delimiter.ToString();
                            break;
                        case NPOI.SS.UserModel.CellType.String:
                            OutputRow += FormatValue(row.Cells[Column].StringCellValue.ToString().Replace('\n', ' ').TrimEnd(), AddQuotes, c) + Delimiter.ToString();//replace the new line character to space due to formatting issue.
                            break;
                        default:
                            result = false;
                            break;
                    }
                    Column++;
                }
                else
                {
                    OutputRow += Delimiter.ToString();
                }

            }

            OutputRow = OutputRow.Remove(OutputRow.Length - 1);
            sw.WriteLine(OutputRow);
        }


        sw.Flush();
        sw.Close();

        return result;
    }`
```

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of issues here contributing to the problem.

First, you are recalculating the `MaxCol` for each row.  If you want a non-ragged right edge, then you need to find the `MaxCol` over *all* rows first, and *then* generate the output.

Second, you are using `row.Cells[]` to try to get a particular cell for the row.  `Cells[]` ignores empty values. So if you happen to have a blank cell somewhere in the row, then all the remaining values will be shifted to the left, and the length of the array will be less than `MaxCol`.  This will lead to an exception if you try to access `row.Cells[MaxCol - 1]` on rows that have at least one blank value.
The solution to this problem is to use the `row.GetCell(index)` method instead.  This method returns the cell at column `index` (0-based), or `null` if that cell is empty.  It is much more straightforward to work with, and will allow you to eliminate the special logic in your code which checks the `ColumnIndex` of the current cell against your loop index `j` to make sure the cell you got is really in the column you expected.

As an additional suggestion, I would recommend retrieving the current cell just once inside your inner loop and assigning it to a variable instead of re-retrieving it multiple times.  This will make your code a little more efficient and easier to read.

Here is the revised code for the `ParseWorksheet` method with all of the above changes:

```
private bool ParseWorksheet(HSSFWorkbook wb, int SheetIndex)
{
    bool result = true;
    HSSFSheet sheet = (HSSFSheet)wb.GetSheetAt(SheetIndex);

    if (sheet.FirstRowNum == sheet.LastRowNum && sheet.LastRowNum == 0) return result;

    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(OutputFileName, true);

    int MaxCol = 0;
    for (int i = sheet.FirstRowNum; i <= sheet.LastRowNum; i++)
    {
        HSSFRow row = (HSSFRow)sheet.GetRow(i);
        MaxCol = Math.Max(MaxCol, row.LastCellNum);
    }

    for (int i = sheet.FirstRowNum; i <= sheet.LastRowNum; i++)
    {
        string OutputRow = String.Empty;
        HSSFRow row = (HSSFRow)sheet.GetRow(i);

        for (int j = 0; j < MaxCol; j++)
        {
            HSSFCell cell = (HSSFCell)row.GetCell(j);
            if (cell != null)
            {
                switch (cell.CellType)
                {
                    case NPOI.SS.UserModel.CellType.Boolean:
                        OutputRow += FormatValue(cell.BooleanCellValue.ToString(), AddQuotes, c) + Delimiter;
                        break;
                    case NPOI.SS.UserModel.CellType.Formula:
                        OutputRow += FormatValue(cell.CachedFormulaResultType.ToString(), AddQuotes, c) + Delimiter;
                        break;
                    case NPOI.SS.UserModel.CellType.Numeric:
                        OutputRow += FormatValue((NPOI.SS.UserModel.DateUtil.IsCellDateFormatted(cell) ? cell.DateCellValue.ToShortDateString() : cell.NumericCellValue.ToString()), AddQuotes, c) + Delimiter;
                        break;
                    case NPOI.SS.UserModel.CellType.Blank:
                        OutputRow += Delimiter;
                        break;
                    case NPOI.SS.UserModel.CellType.String:
                        OutputRow += FormatValue(cell.StringCellValue.ToString().Replace('\n', ' ').TrimEnd(), AddQuotes, c) + Delimiter; //replace the new line character to space due to formatting issue.
                        break;
                    default:
                        result = false;
                        break;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                OutputRow += Delimiter;
            }
        }

        OutputRow = OutputRow.Remove(OutputRow.Length - 1);
        sw.WriteLine(OutputRow);
    }

    sw.Flush();
    sw.Close();

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!